# Attempting to use JSON to stringify an object that holds an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

When trying to stringify an object that holds an array of objects, I'm getting an empty array when I can see I have values.

```
 filterDto: {
            Expressions: []   
        },

/* Using a tempArray to see if its an object issue of my filterDto.Expressions */

fnBuildFilterValues: function() {

            var invoiceObj = this;

             var tempArray = new Array();


              $("#tblExpressions tr").each(function() {

                var doWeAddRow = false;
                var filterObject = {
                    "Field": {},
                    "Condition": {},
                    "DataValue": {}
                };

                $(this).find(":input").each(function() {

                    if (  $(this).attr('name') === 'ddlFieldExp' ) {
                        filterObject.Field =  $(this).val();
                    }
                    if (  $(this).attr('name') === 'ddlConditionExp' ) {
                        filterObject.Condition =  $(this).val();
                    }
                     if (  $(this).attr('name') === 'tbDataExp' ) {
                        filterObject.DataValue =  $(this).val();
                    }

                }); /* Inner loop */

              tempArray.push(filterObject); 

              }); /* Outer loop */

              invoiceObj.filterDto.Expressions = tempArray;
        },
```

And what I want is to use something like:

```
     var objToString = {};
     objToString = JSON.stringify(invoiceObj.filterDto)
```

I've tried using = {} as a remedy but I still end up with ObjToString being empty when my array is populated. It's show as this:   `{"Expressions":[]}`

If I do a quickwatch in VS on the right hand portion, the JSON.Stringify I get this:

```
    JSON.stringify(invoiceObj.filterDto) 
    "{"Expressions":[{"Field":"6","Condition":"0","DataValue":"2"}]}"   String
```

But why is the ObjToString showing an empty result?

Comment: invoiceObj.filterDto.Expressions = tempArray;

Comment: Where are you doing the JSON.stringify()?  You don't show us that.  I'm guessing that you aren't doing JSON.stringify() on the right thing.  FYI, initializing a variable to an object does absolutely nothing when you then just assign it something else.

Comment: I can do var test = JSON.stringify(invoiceObj.filterDto) right below the exit of that function and I get the same result. I'm calling the stringify later inside a jqGrid post, but the issue lies before that with how this object gets formatted from JSON

Comment: Do you have a public page, we can see this in action?  Stepping through it in the debugger and examine variables as you go will show what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've pasted is working fine as evidenced [by this code](http://jsbin.com/epajig/edit#javascript,html,live) (JSON serialization in console.log).

Is your issue that `fnBuildFilterValues` is not called before the serialization attempt? Is your issue that any of your selectors aren't yielding any results? The problem does not appear to be with the pasted code.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what is going on. I call fnBuildFilterValues, then I reload a grid after the function returns:  $('#gridMaster').trigger("reloadGrid"); but its reloading without the updated postData, and using the first entry postdata each time ( the empty version of course )  Thank you for the push.